# how to transfer an object to a header fetchBaseQuery

Tags: api, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

I'm working with api for movies, and to create a request to the server, I need to pass it to the header object

```
{
    'X-API-KEY': 'there is apikey',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
```

I make requests using RTK Query

```
export const filmsApi = createApi({
reducerPath: 'awaitsFilms',
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: url,
}),
endpoints: (build) => ({
    getAwaitsFilms: build.query({
        query: () => `top?type=TOP_AWAIT_FILMS`,
    }),
}),
```

})

how do I pass this header object to fetchBaseQuery?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#prepareheaders)

```
import type { RootState } from './store'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: '/',
  prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
    const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.token

    // If we have a token set in state, let's assume that we should be passing it.
    if (token) {
      headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
    }

    return headers
  },
})
```